Napi.rs : build for linux, windows and darwin
I created a rust node addon, I need to compile it for linux-gnu, windows-msvc, and darwin
Seems like you can just put the "triples.default" to true , or list the 3 target in additional
However, when calling
napi build --platform --release
it generated a mylib.win32-x64-msvc.node and stops here, what I am missing here :

{
  "name": "mylib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  "napi": {
    "name": "mylib",
    "triples": {
      "defaults": true
    }
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@napi-rs/cli": "^2.18.2",
    "ava": "^6.0.1",
  },
  "ava": {
    "timeout": "3m"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "artifacts": "napi artifacts",
    "build": "napi build --platform --release",
    "build:debug": "napi build --platform",
    "prepublishOnly": "napi prepublish -t npm",
    "test": "ava",
    "version": "napi version"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.1.1"
}

